# Does Ruby have a gem for analyzing sentences?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text, rubygems, nlp

What I want is to be able to parse a sentence and classify the words in it as a noun,verb,adjective...etc

I'm aware of [Ruby Wordnet](http://deveiate.org/code/ruby-wordnet/index.html) and a few other similar projects, but I want something that's a lot simpler to use. Also, I'm open to any suggestions on how I could accomplish this without even requiring a gem.

Comment: I recently made a gem for [wit.ai](http://wit.ai), an external nlp service, called [wit_bot](http://bensites.com/wit_bot/). It can take a sentence and extract the intent, and any entities expressed in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently used [engtagger](https://github.com/yohasebe/engtagger) to accomplish what you're describing. It's a pure Ruby gem, so it has no dependencies, but it is pretty old and has some quirks. Still, it was fast enough and accurate enough for my purposes.

As for doing part-of-speech tagging without a gem... it turns out that it's more complicated than you might think. You could implement a Brill tagging algorithm on your own, but that's probably not the best use of your time.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, appreciate it.